# Make MonoDevelop respect smcs.rsp

Tags: mono, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

It's possible to create global defines, by placing them in smcs.rsp, and when you hit play - you'll notice those parts of the code are hit and everything is acting as if it should.

However when editing the source in MonoDevelop, it does not recognize the constants that are set in that file.
Leaving you with text that looks like this:
[image]

This makes it hard to keep track of what the current constant values are and requires mentally tracking what is turned on and off despite the editor constantly telling you otherwise.

Is it possible to get monodevelop to respect that file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method of using smcs.rsp is pretty old and is not needed after unity3d 4.x. Before 4.0 there is not way of doing it without smcs.rsp file but things have changed, the constants can be added from game itslef.

Go to Edit->Project Settings->Player and in the inspector, choose other settings and u will see configuration title, in the box below specify your symbols one by one followed by **;**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer is definitely correct, however the problem is that it must be done per platform. Since however that's the only way to do it i'll mark your answer as correct

Comment: I see that as an added advantage actually, i can keep the constants per platform. I had to do a lot to achieve that with the old method.

Comment: The more i've thought about it, the more I'm inclined to agree

Comment: This did not answer the question. It only provided an alternative. What about distributing tools? I don't think the platform symbols will install with a UnityPackage, will it?

Comment: it doesnt get included with packages, you should be syncing the settings manually. Well this is as off 4.0, but i doubt that it has been changed recently

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And once again -1 to the Unity3d docs team. Why they leave archaic stuff in there...